# extract data by regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I have this string:

```
"irrelevant(AB:1;CD:2;EF:3)"
```

and I need to find a way to extract the `AB`, `CD` and `EF` values (1, 2 and 3 in the example) either as individual variables or as an array, using only JS functions.

The irrelevant part may have `(` `)` `:` and `;` but the `(AB:1;CD:2;EF:3)` part is always at the end. The values are always numeric, of variable length, and the labels are always 2 uppercase letters.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking someone to write a regular expression for you.  What do you have so far?

Comment: Try yourself.  anyway, examples of strings are needed.

Comment: The easiest one is: str.split(/[^0-9]*/). It returns array of these values.

Comment: I had been trying along the lines of "irrelevant(AB:1;CD:2;EF:3)".match(/[AZ][AZ]*/g) without success.  Dupadupa suggestion does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Change ( to ({ and ) to }) and ; to , and you have JSON

Comment: I ended up using str.split("(").pop().split(/[,):]/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var txt = "irrelevant(AB:1;CD:2;EF:3)";
var m = txt.match(/(?:([A-Z]{1,}))\:([0-9]{1,})/gi);
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    var p = m[i].split (":");
    str += "Letters: " + p[0] + " - Number: " + p[1] + "\n";
}
​alert (str)​;
```

Look at this example in action [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqDUh/)

Regards,
Victor